# RANK () function in update sql

Tags: sql, db2, rank, dense-rank

I have 2 tables with incorrect Rank like below. is it possible to compare the data between these 2 tables and rank it based on the data available in the first table and rank the not available record in the first table in the value .

Table1:

```
PRODUCT1    LINE1      RANK1
12345       XXXX         1
12345       YYYY         2
12345       ZZZZ         3
34556       GGGG         1
```

my table2 is currently having the below output

Table 2:

```
PRODUCT2 LINE2 SCORE RANK2 
12345    GGGG  100    1 
12345    JJKJ  90     2 
12345    WEJJ  80     3 
12345    CCCC  70     4 
12345    XXXX  60     5 
12345    YYYY  50     6 
12345    ZZZZ  40     7 
34556    AAAA  90     1 
34556    GGGG  80     2 
34556    HHHH  90     3 
34556    FFFF  80     4
```

I am expecting my table2 output as below after the update

```
PRODUCT2 LINE2 SCORE RANK2 
12345    XXXX   70    1 
12345    YYYY   50    2 
12345    ZZZZ   40    3 
12345    GGGG   100   4 
12345    JJKJ   90    5 
12345    WEJJ   80    6 
12345    CCCC   70    7 
34556    GGGG   80    1 
34556    HHHH   90    2 
34556    FFFF   80    3 
34556    AAAA   90    4
```

The query output is like below ,

```
PRODUCT2 LINE2 SCORE RANK2 
12345    XXXX   70    1 
12345    YYYY   50    2 
12345    ZZZZ   40    3 
12345    GGGG   100   4 
12345    JJKJ   90    5 
12345    WEJJ   80    6 
12345    CCCC   70    7 
34556    GGGG   80    1 
34556    HHHH   90    8 
34556    FFFF   80    9 
34556    AAAA   90    10
```

Due to the   (SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM TEMP) in the answer it takes the max rank from the temp irrespective of the product number and assign the max number as rank for the remaining products. in this case 7 is the maximum rank number in product1 so it assigns the rank as 8,9,10 for the not available lines in table 2

Comment: are you really using both DB2 and Oracle ?

Comment: I am using DB2, removed the incorrect oracle tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
WITH TEMP AS (                                                    
    SELECT B.PRODUCT2,                                                
    B.LINE2, B.SCORE,                                                
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () RANK                                        
    FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2                                             
    B WHERE A.PRODUCT1 = B.PRODUCT2 AND A.LINE1 = B.LINE2             
)                                                                 
SELECT * FROM TEMP 
UNION                                          
SELECT PRODUCT2, LINE2, SCORE, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () + (SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM TEMP) RANK           
FROM TABLE2 C                                                     
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                                                
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE PRODUCT1 = C.PRODUCT2 AND LINE1 = C.LINE2
    ) 
ORDER BY RANK
```

Adding answer based on change in question

---

If you have different products, then while ranking them using rownumber, use Partition. This will rank "within" the partition, product in your case.

```
WITH TEMP AS (                                                   
    SELECT B.PRODUCT2,                                           
    B.LINE2, B.SCORE,                                            
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by PRODUCT2) RANK               
    FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2                                        
    B WHERE A.PRODUCT1 = B.PRODUCT2 AND A.LINE1 = B.LINE2        
)                                                                
SELECT * FROM TEMP                                               
UNION                                                            
SELECT PRODUCT2, LINE2, SCORE,                                   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by PRODUCT2)                    
+ (SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM TEMP where temp.product2 = C.product2) RANK                              
FROM TABLE2 C                                                    
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                                               
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE PRODUCT1 = C.PRODUCT2 AND LINE1 = 
C.LINE2  )                                                       
ORDER BY product2 , RANK
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution , can you please add the full SQL?. looks like it partial.

Comment: @ChimbuDurai No its not partial, I ran in my DB after creating similar tables

Comment: @uSeruSher- yes its works but the product number is not same for all the lines. I have updated the table values in the question with more details. could you please take a look into it...

Comment: @uSeruSher-it ranks the item number but not ranks the lines as expected and i can also see it misses the next rank number . I have updated the question with the results ...could you please take a look into it..

Comment: @uSeruSher- the output suppose to contain the product1 in the same order , Here i can see it ranks the product1 based on the number.

Comment: @@uSeruSher - I have now added order by function in the temp folder and changed the max(Rank-1) and it now does the work. Could you please let me know how to achieve this using an update . for example 

UPDATE PRODUCT2 SET RANK2 = ( above results) ;

Comment: The query output looks good if the same PRODUCT & likes are available in both the tables. but in some cases the product1 contains less lines but product2 contains more rows. in that case it gives the wrong rank number. i have updated the question with the details. could you please take a look into it ?

Comment: @@uSeruSher- I tried to remove the condition A.PRODUCT1 = B.PRODUCT2 in temp  but the it gives me more results and the rank is also not in correct order

Comment: @@uSeruSher - I have added few more details in the question, could you please take a look into it..

Comment: @ChimbuDurai Did u modified SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM TEMP to (SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM TEMP where temp.product2 = C.product2)? You gotta try :P